# Change wallpaper every 10 minutes on Qtile

Tags: python, python3

I want to change my desktop's wallpaper every 10 minutes (or any other arbitrary amount of time) in with Qtile. I currently have a script written in bash that uses `feh` to set the wallpaper, but this isn't ideal because if Qtile is started multiple times (logout, login), then multiple instances of this script will be running in the background.

So, I want to implement this inside Qtile's config.

Qtile allows you to set a `Screen` object's wallpaper via the `wallpaper_image` property. It also has a command for its scripting shell that allows you to set it.

So, what I need, is a Python function that runs every 10 minutes (without halting the entire OS of course) and sets it. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to implement this with this code snippet:

```py
import os
import random
from libqtile import qtile
from typing import Callable
from settings import WALLPAPERS_PATH


class Timer():
    def __init__(self, timeout: int, callback: Callable) -> None:
        self.callback = callback
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.call()

    def call(self) -> None:
        self.callback()
        self.setup_timer()

    def setup_timer(self) -> None:
        self.timer = qtile.call_later(self.timeout, self.call)


def set_random_wallpaper() -> None:
    wallpapers = [
        os.path.join(WALLPAPERS_PATH, x) for x in os.listdir(WALLPAPERS_PATH) if x[-4:] == ".jpg"
    ]
    wallpaper = random.choice(wallpapers)
    set_wallpaper(wallpaper)


def set_wallpaper(file_path: str) -> None:
    for screen in qtile.screens:
        screen.cmd_set_wallpaper(file_path, 'fill')
```

I create a `Timer` class to automate setting it up. You just create a `Timer` object, and it will restart itself once it triggers the callback. It will also call the callback on creation, but this is trivial to change if you want to.

To run this on startup, do this:

```py
@hook.subscribe.startup_once
def setup_wallpaper_timer():
    wallpaper.Timer(
        WALLPAPER_TIMEOUT_MINUTES * 60, wallpaper.set_random_wallpaper)
```